# native generator class in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, id-generation

I have this part of hibernate mapping xml file, and I was looking for a good example for what does native mean.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.hib.Task" table="tasks">
  <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
```

I know it's something related to unique identifier property, but I would really like to have an example.

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm new to hibernate and programming in general :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Native means 
 Your generator will use identity or sequence columns according to what your current database support.

Docs explained about each strategy here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

**native**

> selects identity, sequence or hilo depending upon the capabilities of the underlying database.

**assigned**

> lets the application assign an identifier to the object before save() is called. This is the **default strategy** if no  element is specified.

For example:
In Mysql if you have primary key column as a auto_increment, the db will be updated using this strategy

Comment: "assigned" is the default strategy for generating the primary. For ref key.https://www.java4s.com/hibernate/generators-in-hibernate/

Comment: Read the 3rd line and that may decide who is nut here.

Comment: @AshishBurnwal Agree with you Ashish. Sorry for linking some random online resource aswell. Edited to point official docs now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

And to complete what Suresh Atta said, you can name the sequence:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.hib.Task" table="tasks">
  <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
   <generator class="native">
     <param name="sequence">s_tasks</param>
   </generator>
  </id>
```

So it will either work for IDENTITY and for SEQUENCE incremented primary key.