# Hibernate primary key violation on two server instances

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application which is running on two servers and both these servers access the same database via Hibernate.
The issue here is when these two applications process large set of data and trying to insert to the same table. There is a primary key violation happens. And from the things I have noticed, hibernate seems to buffer some number of primary key ids. eg. If server A insert data into id 100 and at the same time server B will be inserting to id 200 or so. I guess this issue is related to above mentioned scenario. Following is my hibernate properties

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtest?autoReconnect=true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <!--        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- 
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
     -->
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbtest</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
    <!--c3po connection pooling  -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

This is the entity which is failing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 3, 2014 4:38:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.dto.AdditionalContacts" table="additional_contacts"
           entity-name="additionalcontacts">
        <id name="contactId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="contactId">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="contactGuid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="contactGuid" />
        </property>
        <property name="contactName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="contactName" />
        </property>
        <property name="salutation" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="salutation" />
        </property>
        <property name="EmailAddress" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="email" />
        </property>
        <property name="includeInEmails" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="includeInEmails" />
        </property>
        <property name="Website" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="website" />
        </property>
        <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="city" />
        </property>
        <property name="state" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="state" />
        </property>
        <property name="postCode" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="postCode" />
        </property>
        <property name="country" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="country" />
        </property>
        <property name="street" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="street" />
        </property>
        <property name="streetLine1" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="streetLine1" />
        </property>
        <property name="streetLine2" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="streetLine2" />
        </property>
        <property name="streetLine3" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="streetLine3" />
        </property>
        <property name="streetLine4" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="streetLine4" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone1" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="phone1" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone2" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="phone2" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone3" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="phone3" />
        </property>
        <property name="fax" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="fax" />
        </property>
        <property name="location" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="location" />
        </property>
        <property access="field" column="createDate" insert="true"
                  name="createDate" update="false" />
        <property access="field" column="modifyDate" insert="true"
                  name="modifyDate" update="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And following is the entity which uses above entity

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 3, 2014 4:38:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.dto.Contacts" table="contact"
           entity-name="contact">
        <id name="cGuid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="contactGuid" />
        </id>
        <property name="org" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="org" />
        </property>
        <property name="Name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
        <property name="FirstName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="firstName" />
        </property>
        <property name="LastName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="lastName" />
        </property>
        <property name="abn" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="abn" />
        </property>
        <property name="active" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="active" />
        </property>
        <property access="field" column="createDate" insert="true"
                  name="createDate" update="false" />
        <property access="field" column="modifyDate" insert="true"
                  name="modifyDate" update="true" />

        <bag name="additionalContactList" table="additional_contact" lazy="false" inverse="true"
             cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="contactGuid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="additionalcontacts"
                         class="com.test.dto.AdditionalContact" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This one is failing on

> cascade="all"

Comment: Please add the Hibernate mapping for the object you are trying to insert

Comment: What kind of ID is being inserted?

Comment: What is your ID generation strategy?

Comment: Hi @Adam I have updated my question

Comment: @diufanman it is the mysql native id generation strategy

Comment: so you mean in your mySql table `additional_contacts`, the id column `contactId` is defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: It seems not make sense to me, if you use auto_increment in mySql will get the primary key violation. So I think it is the problem of the id generation strategy in your config file `<generator class="increment" />`, may be you try this `<generator class="native"/>`, please also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373015/native-generator-class-in-hibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `AUTO_INCREMENT`. This way MySQL will manage the creation of IDs, so the servers won't have to synchronize. Change the DB column to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`. In Hibernate change the generator type to `native`.

Other alternatives would be to use UUID as the primary key.

Newer versions of Hibernate have other generators that can be used that are better than `native`.